# System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 010000a0 from typeref (expected class 'Camera' in assembly '')'

Tags: xamarin, android-camera

I was following the documentation here https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin but still encountered this issue.

Any ideas?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90FvV.png)

Update:
I got it working already. 
Xamarin Forms and Xamarin Essentials packages under Android Project must also be updated. Here's a working one: https://github.com/arnelirobles/AppTestCamera

Comment: Media Plugin works for the cross platform project. To use this library, please create a Xamarin.Forms project. If you want achieve this on Xamarin.Android, you could use the `Intent`. Check the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971608/android-camera-and-photo-picker-intent

Comment: I am actually using Xamarin.Forms project

Comment: Did you install the nuget package on the android platform project?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I did. I got it working though - Xamarin essentials in android must also be updated. I'll just add in the question.

Comment: You could post your solution and mark it as the answer. It'll help others who face the similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I got it working already. It appears that every time I create a Xamarin Forms Project it doesn't use the latest package version on Xamarin.Form and Xamarin.Essentials.

To resolve here's what I did. Via Nuget Package Manager

Xamarin Forms Project
1. Install Package Xam.Plugin.Media (5.0.1)
2. Update Xamarin.Forms Package (4.6.0.800)
3. Update Xamarin.Essentials Package (1.5.3.2)

Xamarin Android Project
1. Update Xamarin.Forms Package (4.6.0.800)
2. Update Xamarin.Essentials Package (1.5.3.2)

Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Essentials packages under Android Project must also be updated.

Here's a working one: https://github.com/arnelirobles/AppTestCamera